Admin backend is very slow to create or edit posts by core meta query
Over the last few weeks, I've noticed that my website's backend has been getting extremely slow, and today it has come to a complete crawl. I installed the Query Monitor and found that this WP core query takes upwards of 40s.
query:
SELECT DISTINCT meta_key
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key NOT BETWEEN '_'
AND '_z'
HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\\_%'
ORDER BY meta_key
LIMIT 30

37 to 40 seconds.
Caller:
meta_form()
wp-admin/includes/template.php:722
post_custom_meta_box()
wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php:825
do_meta_boxes()
wp-admin/includes/template.php:1456

Rows:
30
Component:
Wordpress Core
SELECT DISTINCT meta_key

I know enough to be dangerous, and at this point, I have no idea how to proceed other than hiring a MySQL/MariaDB developer.
Any thoughts on how I could do this without hiring someone else?

Does this answer your question? Admin: very slow edit page caused by core meta query

Not exactly, as that's an older version of WordPress. I did some digging last night, and someone on Reddit recommended nuking the meta box from loading, so I did that. It's much faster, but there's still some slow down.
